# miniOrange/Okta - Logging into a Wordpress logs you into Okta

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, okta, service-provider, idp

I have successfully set up SSO for a client Wordpress site using the miniOrage SSO plugin and Okta as the IDP. The client can click on the application icon in Okta and they are signed on to the wp site. They can also use the Okta SSO link to sign into their wp site as long as they are already signed into Okta.

What I want is this:

- Initial state: The use is logged out of both the wp site and Okta
- The user visits the wp site and is asked to log in (default wp login).
- The user proceeds to login with their wp credentials.
- MiniOrage now logs the user into Okta then redirects the user back to the wp site.
- The user can now click on other Okta SSO links on a wp site page for other applications (Service Providers, such as Salesforce, etc.)
- Upon clicking the SSO links the user is signed into the respective SP without being asked to sign into Okta since MiniOrange did that when the user logged into the wp site. Hopefully!

Can this be done with miniOrange? I have not been able to locate an example of this exact scenario.

---

I can accomplish this using the Okta sign in widget on a custom login page.
https://developer.okta.com/code/javascript/okta_sign-in_widget#sign-in-to-okta-and-sso-directly-to-an-app
However I would rather use the miniOrange solution if possible. This is how the sign in widget flow would look:

- The user visits the wp site and sees a login page.
- The user logs in with Okta credentials (not wp).
- They are now logged into Okta not the wp site.
- The widget redirects the user to the SSO link for the wp site.
- The user sees the wp site and is logged into it.
- The user is signed into Okta and the wp site.

Same end goal and I know this works but it requires a custom login page and setting up the Okta sign in widget.

Comment: As much as you might not want to use the login widget, it is the way to go. You can use Server Side code to authenticate against Okta from the WP Site, but to do that you would have to redirect the User to Okta to establish their session, and you have to consider Multifactor, which would be a lot of code.  I'm not familiar with MiniOrange. There is also an Javascript Auth SDK that Okta provides that can do things like detecting if a User has an Okta Session if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this wordpress plugin: https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-wordpress-sign-in-widget